# How to get only "true" variables from SAT model?

Tags: z3

Consider that I have a simple SMT-lib formula:

```
(declare-const a Bool)
(declare-const b Bool)
(declare-const c Bool)
(declare-const d Bool)
(assert (or a b))
(assert (or d c))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

When SAT solver gives a model. It provides all variables with there true/false values. But I want only "True" value assigned variables. It is possible with Z3??

Answer (score 5):

Here's a z3py script that accomplishes this.  http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/fp5k

I think to interact with / traverse the model, you need to work with an API.

```
a,b,c,d = Bools('a b c d')

s = Solver()

s.add( Or(a, b) )
s.add( Or(c, d) )

s.check()
m = s.model()
print m

for t in m.decls():
  if is_true(m[t]):
    print t
    print m[t]
```

Comment: Thanks, for your prompt reply.. But I don't want to traverse the entire variable. May be I have a large number of variables then I have check their assignment in linear time. I thought as Z3 knows variable assignment is there any configuration that will gives only "true" valued variables.

Comment: Taylor's solution prints the "true" value variables in linear time. Keep in mind that this is way faster than `s.check()`.

Comment: Thanks Leonardo de Moura, I meant that, if I follow Taylor's solution then I have to check all variable assignments in linear time. But I don't want to do in that way. I asked - is there any kind of configuration for Z3 so that it will always gives model with only "true" valued variables?

Comment: This option does not exist. Even if we add it, it will probably do essentially what Taylor is proposing. I'd like to emphasize that linear time steps are irrelevant in the context of Z3. If your problem is so big that this linear step is an issue, then Z3 will probably not be able to solve the problem anyway. Keep in mind that `s.check()` is exponential in the worst case.